# Immutability in a for in loop when adding an object to an array

Tags: javascript

I have a `for of` with a `for in` loop inside it, that gets a result from a Neo4J database. Using `Object.assign`, I take the result object and assign a property from it to a new object. My understanding is this is immutability.

I then want add the new result object to an array for reach result returned.

I can declare an empty array outside the loop and use `Array.concat` to create new array for each iteration. Another option could be to use Array.push. Neither of these feel immutable because I am either pushing to an array, or overwriting a variable.

Is there a way to end up with a results array, of all object, that is immutable?

```
let results = []
for (const row of argsArray) {
    for (const key in row) {
        const neo4jPropInUse = await neo4j.session(null, cypher.ngp(key, row[key]))
        if (neo4jPropInUse.length !== 0) {
            console.log('IN USE DETECTED')
            const thingResult = Object.assign({}, {
                [thingSerialNumber]: neo4jPropInUse[0].get(`RESULT`).properties[thingSerialNumber],
                key: key
            })
            results = results.concat([thingResult])

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: encapsulate the array as a property of a wrapper object then `.freeze()` the wrapper object?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you declare an object with const you can still modify its contents, you just can't reassign it anymore. If your goal is to return an unmodifiable array after the loops are finished you can use Object.freeze which will stop you from modifying the object (shallowly).

```
Object.freeze(results);
```

Now it will throw an error if you try to push or pop from that array. Note that this is a "shallow freeze" and you will still be able to modify any values inside objects that are part of the array. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Currently, each result object is create and does not change. The issue is that I need each object to go into an array so that I end up with an array that has X number of objects in it. The length of the array going in is unknown so I can't use const `result1`, const `result2` =, etc. I need to be able to generate a new array for each result and wind up with a final array at the end.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little unsure what you are asking, you can declare results as a const array and still push values into it. Then when you have your final array you can freeze it so the contents then can't be modified.

Comment: @Kainan instead of doing results = results.concat([thingResult]), just do results.push(thingResult);

Comment: Array.push push would definitely work but based on my understanding, that would not be immutable. My current code works well, except I am overwriting results with each iteration.

Comment: @Kainan neither is what you have right now, but after the loops are finished you call Object.freeze(results); and that is about as immutable as you are gonna get in JS unfortunately.

Comment: @Kainan basically the const will prevent you from reassigning results, and then Object.freeze will prevent you from adding or deleting anything new to the array.

Comment: Right, but what I'd like to do is avoid pushing as well as overwriting results. I have no idea how to achieve this without mutating results one way or the other. Hope that makes sense. The loop return more than 1 result.

Comment: @Kainan haha not too sure about that honestly, maybe just make a regular array first then make a const copy and then freeze. Javascript wasn't really built for immutability, and honestly you still need to build the array somehow. Is there a particular reason you want to do it this way?

Comment: There is no specific reason the than to try make it immutable. :) It works wonderfully the way that it is and JavaScript provides multiple tools even though they involve mutating (i.e. push). I think you are right, I should just leave it the way it is since there is no real way to pull it off.

Comment: @Kainan well I mean the const declaration and freeze will get you there, I means its not the classical sense of "immutability" but it will prevent reassignment and modification on the array, and it is done in different steps lol. But anyways goodluck!